# How to confirm bandwidth upgrade in Internet

Tags: networking

I am planning to upgrade my internet bandwidth from 150 Mbps to 350 Mbps in my office network. How do I confirm that this upgrade has been completed by service provider and I am getting 350 Mbps?

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask the ISP if they offer the facility to test your bandwidth. If they don't, then simply going to a bandwidth test site, i.e. [www.speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) would provide you the same details.

Keep in mind that in order to more accurately get the speed, you need to turn off any background applications that might use your internet connection, i.e. a download client. That way you guarantee all bandwidth are dedicated to the test.